# How to download file from browser at download path without servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jhipster

I am working on Spring Jhipster java application with front end in angularjs.
My requirement is to export data in csv file then download that exported file to download path of browser.

I know it can be done using servlet, but we are not using servlet then how can I accomplish without servlet using core java code.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, if you are exporting csv file and you have that file object then you can easily copy this file with `FileUtils.copyFile(source, dest);` or

```
private static void copyFileUsingChannel(File source, File dest) throws IOException {
FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
FileChannel destChannel = null;
try {
    sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
    destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
   }finally{
       sourceChannel.close();
       destChannel.close();   }}
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks Hiren, I don't want to copy, for now I am creating csv file at some path at local system. But I want this path to be as download folder and user should see the exported file in browser as downloading on click of export button.

Comment: If the file is served by your JHipster app, it will be served by a servlet even if's just the default servlet from embedded tomcat which serves it from a server directory. Otherwise you could serve it from nginx for instance.